# Executors do not spin correctly when launched separately

Tags: ros, ros2, threads

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to build a modular package in which you can model some ROS systems using YAML files.
You can find the github repository here:

https://github.com/HarunTeper/ros_system_model

However, when launching "launch_system.launch.py", the created executors do not spin correctly in their corresponding threads, but are somehow stuck in the spinning process without executing the nodes.
In "src/system_composition.cpp" I try to create a vector of executors and create a separate thread for each that I also save in a vector. While everything is generated correctly, the executors are not spinning correctly.

What do I need to change to get the correct behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405809/executors-do-not-spin-correctly-when-launched-separately/) by [HarunTeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/76567/harunteper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the issue by saving all created nodes in a separate vector.

---

Originally posted by [HarunTeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/76567/harunteper/) with karma: 13 on 2022-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0